# Files getting renamed while using file upload in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, file-upload, bootstrap-4

I am using file upload control in my `Django` application (Code is mentioned below). I know `Django` uses two `FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS` to process file upload request.

> **Memory based**: If the file size is smaller than 2.5mb than it uses `MemoryFileUploadHandler` and saves the files in memory.
>
> **Disk based**: If the file size is larger than 2.5mb then it uses `TemporaryFileUploadHandler` and saves the files on disk.

I am strictly using 2nd approach by removing `MemoryFileUploadHandler` from `request` token. What I have observed is that files are getting renamed before getting saved in the `/tmp` folder.

```
sample_01.pdf --> /tmp/tmpqj9jb13w.upload.pdf
sample_02.pdf --> /tmp/tmph1u_6x4r.upload.pdf
sample_03.pdf --> /tmp/tmp8p5uoh4g.upload.pdf
sample_04.pdf --> /tmp/tmpuwis6ar0.upload.pdf
sample_05.pdf --> /tmp/tmpq24bk6tm.upload.pdf
```

Because of this it is getting very difficult to identify the files. Is there any way to keep the name of the files as it is.

```
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" multiple>
<label class="custom-file-label" for="fileupload">Choose files</label>
</div>

if request.method == 'POST':
    files_list = request.FILES.getlist('fileupload')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored) about why the name is being generated.

The reason that the TemporaryFileUploadHandler generates just what it says it does: temporary files.  Once you get them onto your server it's up to you to decide what you want to do with them (process it, save it, etc..).  Essentially you should not be looking in the /tmp folder for anything.  Instead you should be using the File Storage API to process the files instead.

It looks like you might try checking the 'name' attribute from the files per [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files), but here's the complete documentation on [handing file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads).